# Tempate function overloading

Tags: c++, templates, overloading

I have a misunderstanding about the template type deduction :) as I couldn't figure out how the sample code below works:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
auto max(T1 a, T2 b)
{
    return  b < a ? a : b;
}

template<typename RT, typename T1, typename T2>
RT max(T1 a, T2 b)
{
    return  b < a ? a : b;
}


int main()
{
    auto c = ::max<int>(4, 7.2);
}
```

So in the main, I have an error saying that the resolution is ambiguous since the two templates fcts are candidate.

So far, what I understand (and hope is correct) is from `::max<int>(4, 7.2);` 
I will have

- ***temlplated Fct 1 Signature*** `double int double` (T1 will be deduced as int, T2 as double ans return type double).
- ***temlplated Fct 2 Signature*** `int int double` (RT will be deduced as int, T1 as int and T2 as double).

As I know after type deduction there is no type conversion so from the signatures I would say the second fuction is the candidate.

Any clue for how the two functions are candidates for template argument int ?

Thank you

Comment: @Nelfeal : in C++ Templates -- the complete guides,the signature of a function is defined :  the return type is taken account if the function is generated from a function template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass a type as argument, then the parameter will not be deduced. Think about it, this would cause all kinds of unexpected things. Hence, for

```
::max<int>(4, 7.2);
```

the two canditats are `max<int,double>` from the first overload and `max<int,int,double>` from the second, which according to their signature are the same (both take an `int` and a `double` as parameters).

Comment: so what about ::max<double>(4, 7.2), what signatures will be for the templated functions ? max<double, double> and max<double, int, double> and then call the 2nd function ?